# want to store last date of month so that the file created on last date should not be removed

Tags: bash

I have created a script for removal of files from a location which were generated 30 days before & removed file name will be redirected to a text file. But now I want to keep a file which is generated last date of every month.

```
#!/bin/bash
function syslog()
{
echo -e "**********************************************************"
echo -e "Logs removal started_$(date +%F-%H:%M:%S)"
echo -e "**********************************************************"
[ -e /backup/logs/older_logs_removed.txt ]
find /backup/logs/all_logs_BKP/ *tar.gz -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -rv } \;#to find & remove files at specific path 
echo -e "**********************************************************"
echo -e "Logs removal completed_$(date +%F-%H:%M:%S)"
echo -e "**********************************************************"
}
syslog | tee -a /var/logs/older_logs_removed.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `{}`, not just `}`, to indicate the found file in `find --exec`.

Instead of calling `rm` directly from `-exec`, call the following script. It only removes the file if its last change wasn't on the last day of month.

To detect such date, it tries to add 1 day to the date, and compares its month with the month of the original date. If it's the same, it wasn't the last day.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
ymd=($(date -r "$file" '+%Y %m %d'))
prev_month=$(date -d ${ymd[0]}${ymd[1]}${ymd[2]}+1day +%m)
if [[ ${ymd[1]} == $prev_month ]] ; then
    rm -rv "$file"
else
    echo Skipping "$file" >&2
fi
```

Comment: ok i will do it too, But can you please help me how i can how i can keep zip file created on moth end